# Appending a string in front of every item in the file using Python

Tags: python

The following is what I am trying to achieve:

```
my_list = ['foo', 'fob', 'faz', 'funk']

string = 'bar'

my_new_list = [ string + x for x in my_list]

print my_new_list
```

The problem is all my words are in a text file. Example:

foo

fob

faz

funk

How to read the text file and write a loop to append the word 'bar' in front of each word and generate a new file?

Comment: So your actual question is how to read a file? What have you tried? What's unclear after reading the documentation on file I/O? What about the duplicate questions and their answers on SO did you not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like that?

```
with open("myfile.txt") as f, open("output.txt", "w") as out:
    for line in f:
        out.write("bar" + line)
```

Comment: You could avoid one indentation level with `with open("myfile.txt") as f, open("output.txt", "w") as out:` I personally think that looks nicer.

Comment: @timgeb I could even get rid of all indentation! Eh, but I guess you're right, it does look a tiny bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of lines in a file using `readlines()` and you can write lines to a file using `writelines()`:

```
with open('/path/to/infile') as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()

string = 'bar'
my_new_list = [string + x for x in lines]

with open('/path/to/outfile', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(my_new_list)
```